# Dynamic rows and inputs

Tags: jquery-ui, spring-3

We have created a questionnaire application.
In that we are providing a user to enter one question and multiple answers and submit to store this questionnaire to DB.

For adding multiple answers for a single question, we need to dynamically add a row by clicking on add button and delete button for deleting the row on UI.

Now my question is:

1. How can I implement the feature of dynamically give a row to enter multiple answers?
2. Once multiple answers are added, how I will get multiple answers in the form field to add that in DB?

Comment: That is a horrible title for a question.

Comment: Change your title, it doesn't explain your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to get all the different values.

E.g.

```
<input type="text" name="answer[]">
<input type="text" name="answer[]">
<input type="text" name="answer[]">
```

Regarding adding the extra rows:

- what have you tried so far?
- What do you have troubles with?
- Do you have a specific question?